# Redirect nginx /index.html to root causing infinite redirects

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I want to avoid having the same HTML page accessible on www.example.com and www.example.com/index.html, i.e i want to redirect the index.html to root.

This:

```
location = /index.html {
        return 301 $scheme://www.example.com;
}
```

is causing me to get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS, a redirect loop.

Any ideas what can i change to make it work?

PS this is my entire nginx conf

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    include /etc/nginx/snippets/letsencrypt-challenge.conf;

    root /var/www/newsite;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name www.example.com;

    location / {
            # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location = /index.html {
            return 301 $scheme://www.example.com;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a detailed treatment of the subject but a simplified explanation just to answer your dilemma. The answer is that you need to abandon the attempt to do what you are doing.

Webservers can only serve specific files such as an xyz.html file. They cannot serve folders.

A call to `https://www.example.com/abc/index.html` is a request for the index.html file in the abc folder of the web root. A call to `https://www.example.com/abc` on the other hand is a request for the abc folder of the web root, which as mentioned, cannot be served.

As you have noticed however, the second call results in `https://www.example.com/abc/index.html` being served. This is because webservers are generally set up such that when a call is made to a folder without specifying a specific file to serve, a redirect to the index.html file in that folder is generated and this is served instead. That is, the webserver internally turns the request for `https://www.example.com/abc` into a request for `https://www.example.com/abc/index.html`.

This is what the `index index.php index.html index.htm;` line in your config does. It says "if there is a request for a folder without a file specified, serve the index.php file instead. If there is not such file, serve the index.html. If there is not such file, serve the index.htm file. If this also does not exist, throw a fit"

The problem is that you then go on to instruct your webserver to redirect requests for `https://www.example.com/index.html` to `https://www.example.com` which the webserver redirects back to `https://www.example.com/index.html` which is again redirected back to `https://www.example.com` in an endless loop until the webserver or your browser finally gives up.

You stated that `I want to avoid having the same HTML page accessible on www.example.com and www.example.com/index.html, i.e i want to redirect the index.html to root.` The question is why? There is absolutely no benefit in doing this and as you found out, you end up in a redirect loop.

You may be trying some SEO stuff but this does not apply here.